# Select one of a row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
SELECT 
    v.ID, 
    v.PhotoID, 
    COUNT(*) AS Cnt, 
    p.PhotoWidth, 
    p.Dir 
FROM `views` v
JOIN `photos` p 
    ON v.PhotoID = p.ID
GROUP BY v.PhotoID DESC 
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

I have the above MySQL command. This works great but in the Photo table each photo is linked to a Directory ID.

What I want now is just one row from each Dir id.

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated this question with the schema of the tables you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove other columns. You need to apply aggregate function to all column except directory id like below. If you need other column apply aggregate function to all columns like in count. I have used 1 instead of * which improve performance of query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS Cnt, 
    p.Dir 
from `photos` p 

GROUP BY p.Dir DESC 
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

**Update:**

So if you would like to get photoID with most views on the top following query will be helpful.

```
SELECT 
    p.ID, 
    v.CountRec AS Cnt

FROM `photos` p 
join 
(select PhotoID, count(1) CountRec from `views` group by PhotoID) v
    ON p.ID= v.PhotoID
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

Comment: But I'm trying to get the Photo with the most views as well.